# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}dx=\ln2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln2.$$ We can write $$\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}=1-\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}},$$ so $$\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}x=a-1-\int_{1}^{a}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ and $$\int_{1}^{a}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n}x\ln(1+x^n)|_{1}^{a}+\int_{1}^{a}\ln(1+x^n)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The last can be manipulated to providing a limit using $e^x\geq x+1$, in our case $x \geq \ln(x+1)$, $x \geq0$. However, I need help from this point on or, if the method is faulty, on the problem itself.
EDIT: Thanks for clarifications. I see the mistake. However, by changing it into$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{1+x^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln2.$ I followed Cosmin's duplicate, but I am unable to grasp the proof, as the level is high. Could you give an easier proof for this than one using improper integrals, please?

Comment: what is $a$ here?

Comment: @Cosmin It's not a duplicate -- the older problem has an extra factor of $n$.

Comment: @clathratus I'm pretty sure $a$ is an arbitrary real greater than $1$.

Comment: for what class is this excercise? normaly for this kind of problem you'll try to see if your function $f_n$ (in your case $\dfrac{1}{x^n+1}$) uniformly converges to some other function $f$ with same domain then interchange the limit with integral sign.

Comment: How exactly is this true? $a$ doesn't appear anywhere on the other side of the equation. Is this to say this entire family of integrals, for $a>1$ are all $\ln2$?

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1354485/478779 might be useful.

Comment: In fact, since that function is uniformly continuous on $(1,\infty)$ we can differentiate both sides with respect to $a$, to get that $\frac{1}{1+a^n} -\frac{1}{2}$. Taking the limit then gives us that $\frac{1}{2} = 0$ which is false. Are you sure there isn't missing information for the problem?

Comment: Is there a simpler proof for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088494/prove-that-lim-n-int-1a-frac11xndx-ln-2?

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be true because of [Prove that $\lim n\int_1^a\frac{1}{1+x^n}dx=\ln 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088494/prove-that-lim-n-int-1a-frac11xndx-ln-2) .

If we would have that $$\int_1^a \frac{1}{x^n+1}dx \to \ln (2) \text{ as } n \to \infty,$$ then we would get that $$n \int_1^a \frac{1}{x^n+1}dx \to \infty \text{ as } n \to \infty,$$ which is false.

Unfortunately, for the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined as $$f_n: [1,a] \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 0,$$ we do not have uniform convergence to $f \equiv 0$ on $[1,a],$ but we do have uniform convergence on $(1,a]$ to $f$. Then you can compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_{1+\epsilon}^a f_n(x)dx \right), $$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ and then taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, you get that your desired limit is $0$.

You can also use Lebesgue's criteria for the Riemann integral instead of a proof with $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is there a simpler proof for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088494/prove-that-lim-n-int-1a-frac11xndx-ln-2?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the sequence of functions, only Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem is a straightforward solution, i.e. no other weaker dominated convergence theorem works (like Arzelà's). A solution without it may be harder to find.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.

Assuming $a > 1$, we can bound
$$\frac1{1+x^n} \le \frac12, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
which is an integrable function on $[1, a]$. On the other hand, since $x \ge 1$, we have that
$$\frac1{1+x^n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\begin{cases} 1, &\text{ if }x = 1 \\ 0, &\text{ if }x \in (1,a]\end{cases} $$

Hence $\left(\frac1{1+x^n}\right)_n$ converges almost everywhere to $0$, so Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem implies:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^a \frac{dx}{1+x^n} = \int_1^a \underbrace{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{1+x^n}\right)}_{=0} \,dx = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

I will be computing $$J_n(a)=\int_1^a\ln(1+x^n)dx$$
First recall the definition of the complex root of a complex number $z$:
$$z^{1/n}=|z|^{1/n}\exp\left[\frac{i}n(2\pi k+\arg z)\right],\qquad k=0,1,..,n-1$$
So if $x$ satisfies $1+x^n=0$ then $$x=\exp\frac{i\pi(2k+1)}n$$
So we define $$\lambda_{n,k}=\exp\frac{i\pi(2k+1)}n$$
And with this we can factor $x^n+1$:
$$x^n+1=(x-\lambda_{n,0})(x-\lambda_{n,1})\cdots (x-\lambda_{n,n-1})=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-\lambda_{n,k})$$
And since $$\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y$$
We have that $$\ln(x^n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln(x-\lambda_{n,k})$$
So
$$J_n(a)=\int_1^a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln(x-\lambda_{n,k})dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_1^a\ln(x-\lambda_{n,k})dx$$
$$J_n(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\ln\left|\frac{j(a-\lambda_{n,k})}{j(1-\lambda_{n,k})}\right|+\lambda_{n,k}-1\right]\qquad\text{where}\  j(z)=z^z$$
I hope this helps.